# How to prevent upgraded Eclipse Oxygen from automatically downgrading

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-oxygen, oomph

I'm trying to Upgrade Eclipse Neon to Oxygen on Windows 10.

I started Eclipse with Administrator privileges and then followed the instructions described in the [Eclipse Wiki](https://wiki.eclipse.org/FAQ_How_do_I_upgrade_Eclipse_IDE%3F).

The upgrade runs without errors and prompts for a restart. After the restart, Oxygen comes up without errors and everything seems fine. But when I close Eclipse and start it again, it's back to Neon, duh.

Oh, how I miss Arch Linux's `pacman`...

Comment: I had this happen too, but tried the upgrade a second time and then removed any neon repositories from the update manager.  It seems like I am fully on oxygen now :/

Answer (score 25, accepted):

I had the same problem. Every restart after the initial upgrade from Neon to Oxygen, I got a "Requirements Update" dialog that prompted me to downgrade some of my components from 4.7 to 4.6 after which point I was back on Neon. Oops. Apparently "Oomph" still thought I should be on Neon and was trying to "fix" things.

I followed the following step outlined here:

https://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/t/1082235/

> open the Installation setup (Navigate -> Open Setup -> Installation)
>   and in the properties view change the product version to say Oxygen

After I did this, Oomph left me on Oxygen after this.

Comment: This "work around" was also required for me to upgrade from Mars. (I had to save the Oxygen version property to apply it before updating).

Comment: I can't find "Navigate -> Open Setup" in Eclipse Neon 4.6.3

Comment: @piegames This answer is to prevent the automatic downgrade from happening after you have upgraded. You need to first upgrade using the instructions linked to by OP.

Comment: This worked for me too, but I had to go through and update to Oxygen again through the Check Updates gui.

Answer (score 2):

I "solved" the problem by

1. downloading the Oxygen installer,
2. installing Eclipse Oxygen as a separate instance,
3. installing all the plugins I need in Oxygen,
4. exporting the preferences from Neon and importing them in Oxygen.

A bit annoying, but it works and is probably still way more effective than figuring out what is going wrong with Eclipse's upgrade mechanism...